# How to find out which plugin create captcha after login?

Tags: plugins, captcha

After logging in I get an extra layer:

[image]
<sub>The URL is `https://quảcầu.cc/wp-login.php?action=postpass`</sub>

This is fine, but now I have a protected post, and after entering password this captcha shows up. After done it the page redirect to a blank page. One needs to re-access the post from the URL bar, then re-enter password again to read it.

So far I only have two security plugins: Jetpack and Wordfence. But even when I have deactivated them, this still persists.

Do you know how to find what cause this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like LiteSpeed reCaptcha - https://blog.litespeedtech.com/2019/03/18/recaptcha-server-wide-protection/

Probalby it was enabled by your hosting provider to protect sites from brute force attacks. I'd suggest you to contact them and explain your issue so they could configure it to make a proper redirect after reCaptcha check.